# PassportJS Compare Confirm Password Field

Tags: express, passport.js, passport-local

I am using PassportJS with my ExpressJS app and I am trying to set up a password confirmation field with my user sign up.  My original thought is to make this a view/controller setup rather than involving a model to simplify this process, but I am having an issue with the way I am trying to achieve this logic as my passportJS localStrategy is not checking that the two field values match. Am I approaching this in the right manner?

**PassportJS logic (req.user && password === confirmPassword):**

```
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var models = require('../app/models/db-index');
var bcrypt   = require('bcrypt-nodejs');

    //Sign Up Logic
    passport.use('local-signup', new LocalStrategy({
        passReqToCallback: true,
        usernameField: 'email'
    }, function(req, email, password, done){
        models.User.findOne({
            where: {
                email: email
            }
        }).then(function(existingUser){
            if (existingUser)
                return done(null, false, req.flash('error', 'Email already exists.'));
            if (req.user && password === confirmPassword) {
                var user = req.user;
                user.firstName = firstName;
                user.lastName = lastName;
                user.email = email;
                user.password = models.User.generateHash(password);
                user.save().catch(function(err){
                    throw err;
                }).then(function(){
                    done(null, user, req.flash('error', 'All fields need to be filled in'));
                });
            } else {
                var newUser = models.User.build({
                    firstName: req.body.firstName,
                    lastName: req.body.lastName,
                    email: req.body.email,
                    password: models.User.generateHash(password)
                });

                newUser.save().then(function(){
                    done(null, newUser);
                }).catch(function(err){
                    done(null, false, console.log(err));
                });
            }
        }).catch(function(e){
            done(null, false, req.flash('error', 'All fields need to be filled in'),console.log(e.email + e.message));
        })
    }));
```

**Route:**

```
*====   /SIGN-UP    ====*/


    siteRoutes.route('/sign-up')

        .get(function(req, res){
            res.render('pages/site/sign-up.hbs',{
                error: req.flash('error')
            });
        })

        .post(passport.authenticate('local-signup', {
            successRedirect: '/app/sign-up/organization',
            failureRedirect: '/sign-up'
        }));
```

**View:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    {{> site/head}}
</head>
<body>
    {{> site/navigation}}
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
            {{#if error}}
                <div class="alert alert-danger">{{error}}</div>
            {{/if}}
            <h1>Sign Up</h1>
            <form action="/sign-up" method="post">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="sign-up-fist-name"  name="firstName" value="" placeholder="First Name">
                <br />
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="sign-up-username"  name="lastName" value="" placeholder="Last Name">
                <br />
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="sign-up-username"  name="email" value="{{user.email}}" placeholder="Email">
                <br />
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="sign-up-password"  name="password" value="" placeholder="Password">
                <br />
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="sign-up-password"  name="confirmPassword" value="" placeholder="Confirm Password">
                    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
            </form>
            <a href="/login">Already have an account? Login here!</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can't find solution, use javascript confirmation. It's simplest way which I use. If you find solution, please share her, I wanna use it.

```
<script>
    function myFunction() {
        var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
        var password2 = document.getElementById("password2").value;
        var ok = true;
        if (password != password2) {
            //$(".alert").alert();
            //alert("Passwords Do not match");
            document.getElementById("alert").style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById("password").style.borderColor = "#E34234";
            document.getElementById("password2").style.borderColor = "#E34234";
            ok = false;
        } else {
            alert("Passwords Match!!!");
        }
        return ok;
    }
</script>
```